# How to trigger a child component validation from parent onSubmit - react

Tags: reactjs

I saw a solution to this in angular, but I want to be able to do it with React.
I have been able to get the data from the child to parent for validation, but I am still unable to trigger the validation on form submission when the field are potential empty.

My child component has all its validation is wrapped in a child component and it trigged by onblur or onchange event.
Any suggestions how I can do this?

```
class MainForm extends Component {

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    const nameFields = [
      {
        id: 'firstame', type: 'text', name: 'firstname', label: 'First name', required: true,
      },
      {
        id: 'lastName', type: 'text', name: 'lastname', label: 'Last name', required: true,
      },
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => (this.handleSubmit(e))} noValidate>
          <div className="form__field--background">
            <div>
              {
                nameFields.map(element => (
                  <div key={element.id} className="form__field--wrapper">
                    <InputField
                      type={element.type}
                      id={element.name}
                      name={element.name}
                      required={element.required}
                      placeholder={element.placeholder}
                      label={element.label}
                      pattern={element.pattern}
                    />
                  </div>
                ))
              }
            </div>
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className="btn btn--red">Update Preferences</button>
        </form>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MainForm;




class InputField extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // this.inputField = React.createRef();
    this.validateField = this.validateField.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      valid: null,
      message: '',
    };
  }
  /**
   * Calls helper function to validate the input field
   * Sets the the state for the validation and validation message
   */
  validateField(e) {
    const props = {
      field: e.target,
      label: this.props.label,
      required: this.props.required,
      min: this.props.min,
      max: this.props.max,
      pattern: this.props.pattern,
      emptyError: this.props.emptyFieldErrorText,
      invalidError: this.props.invalidErrorText,
    };
    let validation = this.state;
    // helper function will return an updated validation object
    validation = fieldValidation(props, validation);
    this.setState(validation);

    return validation;
  }

  /**
   * Calls validateField method if field is a checkbox.
   * Calls inputHandler callback.
   * Handles the callback isValid state to parent component.
   */
  handleInputChange(e) {
    if (e.target.required && e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
      this.validateField(e);
    }
    this.handleInputValidation(e);
  }

  handleInputValidation(e) {
    if (typeof this.props.isValid === 'function') {
      this.props.isValid(this.validateField(e), this.props.name, e.target.value);
    }
  }

  handleOnBlur(e) {
    if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      this.validateField(e);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {this.props.label}
        </label>
        {this.props.helpText &&
        <p className="form-help-text">{this.props.helpText}</p>
        }
        <input
          type={this.props.type}
          id={`field-input--${this.props.id}`}
          name={this.props.name && this.props.name}
          required={this.props.required && this.props.required}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder && this.props.placeholder}
          onBlur={e => this.handleOnBlur(e)}
          onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)}
        />
        {this.state.valid === false &&
            <span className="form-error">
              {this.state.message}
            </span>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default InputField;
```

Comment: I see that you have a property `noValidate` in the form. Could that be the issue why you're not triggering validation?

Comment: the noValidate just stops the browser from showing the native html5 validation.

Comment: hi. did you solve that? i'm facing the same need here.

Answer (score -1):

You could ensure that the parent component is aware of the child by getting the child to let the parent know it exists in an early lifecycle method.

I.e:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.tellParentEntryExists();
    }
}
```

That would mean when it comes to validation, the parent has an entry to validate?

Comment: Not sure I understand - how would I trigger the validation(e) 
call the this.tellParentEntryExists(e){} in the onSubmitHandler,  the main issue it the validation is triggered on onchange or onblur event, so I want it trigger on submission